# Chart for wrong Bracha Rishona?

Tags: blessing, food

I found [this neat chart](http://westmountshul.com/documents/Review%20Sheet%2027.pdf) for what to do when you have said a wrong Bracha Achrona, and whether or not it was effective after the fact. I am curious, does anyone have a similar chart which will tell me when a wrong Bracha Rishona will be effective after the fact?

Comment: Hi michael. Just remember to be careful with charts like these as they often contain implicit decisions that not everyone agrees to. (For instance should needing to say birkat hamazon again after accidentally saying borei nefashot really be labeled questionable?)